# Creating user accout from server side using Meteor js

Tags: javascript, meteor

i'm trying to create a user from server side using meteor js, when testing the code it show me this error in navigator console `Error invoking Method 'addNewUser': Internal server error [500]`.
this is my code:
`/imports/api/users/methods.js` :

```
Meteor.methods({
   addNewUser(user) {
       console.log(user);
       const email = user.emails[0].adresse;
       const newUser = {
           username: user.username,
           email: email,
           password: user.password
       };
       Accounts.createUser(newUser, (err) => {
           if (err) {
               toastr.error(err.reason,'faild');
              // this.done(new Error("Submission failed"));
           } else {
               toastr.success('Registred with success !', 'welcome');
               FlowRouter.go('home');
           }
       });
   }
});
```

`/imports/ui/pages/create-account.js:`

```
AutoForm.hooks({
    formCreateAccount: {
        onSubmit(user) {
            Meteor.call('addNewUser', user);
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: console.log(user); //what is this output log ?

Comment: @Aboopallikara it show data sent from the form

Comment: `Object {username: "mm", emails: Array[1], password: "000", confirm: "000"}`

Comment: i solve it .. no calbacks in server side